# Creating SWF projector for MAC (on MAC)

Tags: flash, flashdevelop

I'm creating a Flash game that uses Google Image Search results as part of its content, and due to crossdomain browser restrictions it won't work in browser.

For PC, I can run the .SWF in Standalone Flash and do "File -> Create projector" and I have an EXE file.

On Mac however, I can't find such an option. I've gotten the game to run, and load content, if I open the SWF with Adobe Flash 5.5, but there are no options like "Create Projector" or "Publish". I've read that it is possible to create a .HQX file for Mac, but I can't find any information on how to do that starting from a SWF file.

**EDIT:**
This is how I make the .EXE

[image]

**EDIT:**
For development of the project, I am using FlashDevelop, which does not have "publish settings" like Adobe Flash does. That's why I'm asking to convert the SWF, because I can't open my FlashDevelop project on a Mac.

Comment: Why not create your file for Mac on the PC? You can Publish an `.app` file for the Mac just as easily as you created the `.exe` file, by selecting the 'Macintosh Project' export option.

Why do you have to go from SWF to HQX on the Mac?

Comment: Is this an option in Adobe Flash or in the player? I'm creating the player in FlashDevelop on windows, which doesn't have a 'Macintosh Project' option. I've updated the question with a screenshot of how I make the .EXE

Comment: It's an option in Adobe Flash Pro.  FlashDevelop is out of my experience.  Perhaps put the flashdevelop tag on this question and see if someone else swings by with an answer.

Answer (score 0):

[image: this is Flash 5.5 with the mac projector right beneath Windows]

This is a screenshot of Flash 5.5. If you're using 5.5 as well then the problem would most likely be the version of flash you're attempting to publish in as some features aren't available to older versions of Flash Player. It should be there though.

Comment: Thanks. However, the project is made in Flashdevelop, not in Flash, which means I can't open the project in Flash or access publish settings. I can open the .SWF in Flash on MAC, and it runs, but then I don't see the publish settings anywhere...

Comment: ohhh my bad, i'll look into flashdevelop as i have not yet.. let you know if i see anything, good luck!

Comment: It seems that the only ways to do that are: try to create projector file from Mac OSX environment or install Adobe Flash Professional.

http://www.flashdevelop.org/community/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=5441